# Can I deduct anything from my Taxes if I send money back home for my educational loan?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, f1-student-visa

For the tax year, I was on an F-1 visa.  I routinely send money back home to India for my educational loan/ family purposes. Can I deduct this from my taxes?

Comment: Do you pay interest on the loans?

Comment: The loan was repayed by a family member to not accrue any interest, however, I am repaying the total amount to the family member.

Comment: Typically it's just interest paid that is deductible, but I'm not sure if there are other opportunities for tax-benefit in your situation.